# MedicOneSystems Livewire Datatables Error: Duplicate Column Name(s): callback_3663396338

Tags: laravel-livewire

So I have been upgrading an existing table for users on an app. As soon as i try to add multiple callbacks that use['id'] i get the Duplicate error.

The two callback Columns involved are these:

```
            Column::callback(['id'], function($id) {
                return User::find($id)->roles->first()->name;
            })
                ->label('Role'),

            Column::callback(['id'], function($id) {
                return view('tables.user.flags', ['id' => $id]);
            })->label('Flags'),
```

Removing either of these makes the table work. I realise that as both are using the id field and this is the most likely reason for the error but my question is how can i resolve this? I have tried adding in a name() and an Attribute in User for role but nothing worked and I mainly got errors about columns not being found in the users table in the database.

Not sure if it helps but the Role column is using `Spatie/laravel-permission`. The flags column however does use columns that are in the User model (is_card_holder, is_account_handler) but shows other flags too.

I am new to Medicones solution having tried to use datatables.net (I had mulitple issues with this so it is being phased out) and rappasoft laravel livewire tables (worked well but lost a lot of search and sort functionality from many columns) I have been told that the one to go with which has the flexibility needed is the mediconesystems solution and so here I am....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different keys for each callback:

```php
            Column::callback(['role_id' => 'id'], function($id) {
                return User::find($id)->roles->first()->name;
            })
                ->label('Role'),

            Column::callback(['flag_id' => 'id'], function($id) {
                return view('tables.user.flags', ['id' => $id]);
            })->label('Flags'),
```

Comment: Ended up moving to rappasoft livewire-tables but great there is a solution for this